# populate div with ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to populate div with some data. This data is called with help of AJAX, JSON and controller function in asp.net mvc4. 
My main goal is to append div with some data.

Here is markup

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(actionName: "GetEncryptedQuery", controllerName: "Home", ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "Post", OnBegin = "searchBegin", OnSuccess = "searchSuccess", OnFailure = "actionFailed"}, htmlAttributes: new Dictionary<string, object>(){{"id","frmSearch"},{"class","form-schedules"}}, routeValues: null))
                                    {
                                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-control-wrapper">
                                                @*<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-origin" placeholder="Origin">*@
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Origin,new {@class="form-control",id="search-origin", placeholder="Origin"})
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.OriginId,new {@class="form-control",id="search-origin-id"})
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-control-wrapper">
                                                @*<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-destination" placeholder="Destination">*@
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Destination,new {@class="form-control",id="search-destination", placeholder="Destination"})
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.DestinationId,new {@class="form-control",id="search-Destination-id"})
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-red pull-right">GO</button>
                                    }
                                <!-- partial search origin ajax -->
                                <div class="search-origin-ajax list-below-origin" id="search-below-origin">



                                </div>
```

Here is AJAX Call

```
$(document).ready(
$("#search-below-origin").change(function(evt) {

    if ($("#search-below-origin").val() != "-1") {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            url: '/Home/PopulateLocation',
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(index, element) {

                    $.html('<a href="#" class="modal-select-origin"><span class="ajax-star"></span><span class="ajax-content">' + element.valueOf("Name") +
                        '</span><span class="ajax-icon-area"><span class="icon-area"></span></span></a>').appendTo("#search-below-origin");
                });
            }
        });
    }
}));
```

and here is a function in "home" controller

```
[HttpGet]
    private ActionResult PopulateLocation()
    {
        var statesResults = from l in _db.Locations.AsParallel()
            select new PseudoLocation()
            {
                Id = l.Id,
                Name = l.Name
            };

        var statesList = Json(statesResults,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return statesList;
    }
```

Comment: What problems are you having with the code?

Comment: data is not appended in div. and when I'm debugging this function is not reached from ajax.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems:

1. You probably meant to make the method `public`:

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult PopulateLocation()
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. `#search-below-origin` is a `div` and does not appear to contain any elements that could trigger the `change` event. Did you mean `#search-origin`?
3. [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is an *instance* method on jQuery. You can create an in-memory html snippet just calling jQuery (using `$`), so you should not need to use `.html` here:

   ```
   $('<a href="#" class="modal-select-origin"><span class="ajax-star"></span><span class="ajax-content">' + element.valueOf("Name") +
       '</span><span class="ajax-icon-area"><span class="icon-area"></span></span></a>')
           .appendTo("#search-below-origin");
   ```

Comment: yeah I meant #search-origin